# Cannot print from Brave browser

Tags: 20.04, printing, brave

Ubuntu 20.04, Brave Version 1.18.75 Chromium: 87.0.4280.101 (Official Build) (64-bit), Fuji Xerox network printer

I can print from all my applications, including Firefox, but not from Brave. When I hit Print, the print dialogue opens but under Destination, the only option shown is "Save as PDF".

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

By coincidence, found the problem. In /Settings/Applications (of Ubuntu, not the browser) there are two entries for the Brave browser, one of them for "Permissions and access". For reasons I shall never know, the switch for "Print documents" was disabled. Enabling this and restarting the browser fixed the issue.